# Подключить удалённый сервер NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Такая ситуация. У меня создан сервер на NodeJS(Проект на готовой платформе, но не суть). Я хочу подключить ещё один сервер, удалённый, чтобы скидывать на него ресурсозатратные вычисления. С помощью каких технологий я могу это сделать?

Comment: а вам не подойдет вариант выпонять ресурсоемкие вычисления в отдельном процессе при помощи child_process?

Comment: дока - https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: небольшой разбор - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqCd4dbaFb4

Comment: общение по запросам, не обязательно http, могут быть сокеты, или rabbit.mq
основной сервер => request => доп серв => вычисления => response => основной сервер

Answer (score 0):

Самый бюджетный вариант - поднять 2 сервера и по http слать запросы с одного на другой. А так, можете почитать про докер, про микросервисы, про сети приватные (чтоб второй сервер наружу не торчал).